# Route 404 page just work on localhost

Tags: codeigniter, routes

I use codeigniter for my project and custom route 404 page. 
My route file :

```
$route['404'] = 'frontend/maintain/page404';
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

On localhost, website route right to my custom 404 page, but on live server it does not, it route to the default 404 page of codeigniter ?
i do not understand why it like that. Please tell me why ? Many thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

On Codeigniter 3 versions the 404 override route only works on one level does not work in sub folders

```
$route['404_override'] = 'page404';
```

Controllers > Page404.php

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But i routed right on localhost, just not right on live server.

Comment: @RyanTran did you make sure the filename and class only have first letter upper case? `Page404.php` and `class Page404 extends CI_Controller {}`

Comment: Sure...all controller names and filenames are upper case.